# Delphi - udp works in local but not works over network

Tags: delphi

I made a simple file transfer program with indy udp socket but there was a problem.

Since UDP does not guarantee the order of data, so I tried making udp reliable manually.

At first, I made a TPacket record which includes Serial Number,Next Number,
Index Number and array of byte(data).

Serial Number is the ID of the packet.
Next Number is the Serial Number of which the receiver needs to receive packet next.
Index Number is the index of the packet, which is used for sorting the packets when the sender sends many packets at once.

The sender divides the data into packets in the fixed length, and sends the total count of packets.

After that the sender tries sending the packets gradually: sends the count of packets, sends the packets, receives the index of error packets, re-sends the error packets.
(The receiver receives the packets and sorts the packets with index and if the missed packets exist the receiver sends the indexes of the missed packets.)

I tried sending a large file.
It works good in local(localhost, hotspot), but it sometimes stops when connected over network.(through AP,internet)

I debugged my app and I found there was a mismatch of Sending-Receiving(in the source, "SendAck" and "RecvAck")(e.g. the sender sends the count of packet and the receiver sends the indexes of error packets... the receiver should have received the count of packet.)

My Source(omitted some parts) :

```
unit UUDPHelper;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, IdUDPClient, IdUDPServer, System.SysUtils,
  System.Math, IdGlobal, IdSocketHandle, UCode, IdExceptionCore, IdStack,
  System.Generics.Defaults, System.DateUtils;

type
  TPacket = record
    Serial:Int64;
    Next:Int64;
    Index:Int64;
    data:TBytes;
  end;
  TIdAck = (IA_OK = 1,IA_FAIL);

  EReadTimeout = class(Exception) end;

  TUDPClient = class(TIdUDPClient)
  private
    RNum:Int64;
    SNum:Int64;

    function ReceiveBuffer:TBytes; overload;

    function StreamToPackets(Stream:TMemoryStream):TList<TPacket>;
    procedure SendAck(Ack:Int64);
    function RecvAck(Timeout:Int64 = -1):Int64;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);

    procedure AtConnected(Sender:TObject);
    procedure AtDisconnected(Sender:TObject);

    procedure Signal; overload;
    procedure Signal(Code:TCode); overload;
    procedure DisconnectSignal;
    procedure ConnectSignal;
    procedure WriteInt64(value:Int64);
    procedure WriteString(str:string);
    procedure WriteStream(Stream:TMemoryStream);
    function ReadInt64():Int64;
    function ReadString():string;
    procedure ReadStream(var Stream:TMemoryStream);
  end;

  TIPNum = record
    IP:string;
    RNum:Int64;
    SNum:Int64;
  end;

  TUDPRead = reference to procedure(const AData:TBytes; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);

  TUDPServer = class(TIdUDPServer)
  private
    IPNumList:TList<TIPNum>;

    function ReceiveBuffer(ABinding:TIdSocketHandle):TBytes;
    procedure SetRNum(RNum:Int64; Idx:Integer);
    procedure SetSNum(SNum:Int64; Idx:Integer);

    procedure SendAck(Ack:Int64; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
    function RecvAck(ABinding:TIdSocketHandle; Timeout:Int64 = -1):Int64;
  public
    AtUDPRead:TUDPRead;

    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);
    destructor Destroy;

    procedure InUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);

    function FindIPNum(IP:string):Integer;
    function GetIPNum(IP:string):TIPNum;
    procedure ClearIPNum;

    function StreamToPackets(Stream:TMemoryStream; IP:string):TList<TPacket>;

    procedure WriteInt64(value:Int64; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure WriteString(str:string; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure WriteStream(Stream:TMemoryStream; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
    function ReadInt64(ABinding:TIdSocketHandle):Int64;
    function ReadString(ABinding:TIdSocketHandle):string;
    procedure ReadStream(var Stream:TMemoryStream; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
  end;

procedure TUDPClient.ReadStream(var Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  count:Int64;
  ack,ack2:TIdAck;

  pList:TList<TPacket>;
  buffer:TBytes;
  packet:TPacket;

  I,J,K:Int64;
  T:Int64;
  Amount:Integer;

  Idxs,Temp:array of Int64;  
  nIdx,TempLen,pn:Integer;

  IsFound:Boolean;
begin
    count:=RecvAck(); // receive the total count of packets.

    pList:=TList<TPacket>.Create();
    I:=0;
    T:=0;
    nIdx:=0;
    SetLength(Idxs,MAX_AMOUNT);
    SetLength(Temp,MAX_AMOUNT);
    while I<count do
    begin
        Amount:=RecvAck(); // receive the count of packets.

        J:=0;
        pn:=nIdx;
        while nIdx<Amount do
        begin
            if T+J>=count then break;

            Idxs[nIdx]:=T+J;
            inc(nIdx);
            inc(J);
        end;

        {Idxs is the array of indexes of packets which will be received soon.}

        for J:=1 to Amount do
        begin
            try
                buffer:=ReceiveBuffer();
            except
                buffer:=nil;
            end;
            if (buffer=nil) or (Length(buffer)=0) then break;

            packet:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
            if Length(packet.data)=0 then break;

            IsFound:=False;
            K:=0;
            while K<pList.Count do
            begin
                if pList[K].Index=packet.Index then
                begin
                    IsFound:=True;
                    break;
                end;
                inc(K);
            end;

            if IsFound then
                pList.Delete(K);

            pList.Add(packet);
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

        pList.Sort(TComparer<TPacket>.Construct(function(const Left,Right:TPacket):Integer
        begin
            Result:=Left.Index-Right.Index;
        end));

        //Finds the missed packets with Idxs array.

        TempLen:=0;
        for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
        begin
            IsFound:=False;
            for K:=I to pList.Count-1 do
                if pList[K].Index=Idxs[J] then
                begin
                    IsFound:=True;
                    break;
                end;

            if not IsFound then
            begin
                Temp[TempLen]:=Idxs[J];
                inc(TempLen);
            end;
        end;

        // counts the packets which is sent normally.            

        J:=I;
        while J < pList.Count do
        begin
            if pList[J].Index <> J then
                break;
            inc(J);
        end;
        I:=J;      

        T := T + Amount - pn;
        Move(Temp[0],Idxs[0],sizeof(Int64)*TempLen);
        nIdx:=TempLen;

        // if there is no missed packet, sends OK sign.
        // else, sends FAIL and error indexes.

        if nIdx=0 then
            SendAck(Int64(IA_OK))
        else
        begin
            SendAck(Int64(IA_FAIL));
            SendAck(Int64(nIdx));
            for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
                SendAck(Idxs[J]);
        end;
    end;
    Finalize(Idxs);
    Finalize(Temp);

    Stream:=PacketsToStream(pList);
    Stream.Position:=0;

    for I:=0 to pList.Count-1 do
        if Length(pList[I].data)>0 then
        begin
            buffer:=pList[I].data;
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

    pList.Free;
end;

procedure TUDPClient.WriteStream(Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  pList:TList<TPacket>;

  buffer:TBytes;
  ack,ack2:TIdAck;

  Amount:Integer;
  I,T:Int64;
  ldt,dt,ot:TDateTime;
  J:Integer;

  Idxs:array of Int64;
  nIdx,pn:Integer;

  ncount:Integer;
  Index:Int64;

  IsFound:Boolean;
  IsExcept:Boolean;
  m:Int64;
begin
    Stream.Position:=0;
    pList:=StreamToPackets(Stream);

    SendAck(Int64(pList.Count)); // sends the total count of packets

    Amount:=30;
    I:=0;
    T:=0;
    SetLength(Idxs,MAX_AMOUNT);
    nIdx:=0;
    ncount:=0;
    ldt:=-1;
    while I<pList.Count do
    begin
        // Fill Idxs array.
        // Idxs array contains the indexes of packets to be sent soon.

        J:=0;
        while nIdx<Amount do
        begin
            if T+J>=pList.Count then break;

            Idxs[nIdx]:=T+J;
            inc(nIdx);
            inc(J);
        end;

        pn:=nIdx;
        SendAck(Int64(nIdx)); // sends the count of packets.

        ot:=Date()+Time();
        for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
        begin
            buffer:=PacketToBytes( pList[Idxs[J]] );
            SendBuffer(TIdBytes(buffer));
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

        ack:=TIdAck(RecvAck(10000)); // receives the ack of the receiver.
        dt:=Date()+Time();

        T:=T+nIdx-ncount;
        if ack=IA_FAIL then    // if failed, fill the idxs array with error indexs.
        begin
            nIdx:=RecvAck();
            for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
                Idxs[J]:=RecvAck();

            ncount:=nIdx;
        end
        else   // if succeeded, clear the idxs array.
        begin
            ncount:=0;
            nIdx:=0;
        end;
        I:=I+pn-nIdx;

        // send-amount controlling //
        if ldt<>-1 then
        begin
            if SecondsBetween(ot,ldt)>SecondsBetween(ot,dt) then
                Amount:=Min(Amount+10,MAX_AMOUNT);
            if SecondsBetween(ot,ldt)<SecondsBetween(ot,dt) then
                Amount:=Max(Amount-10,Max(nIdx,30));
        end;

        ldt:=dt;
    end;
    Finalize(Idxs);

    for I:=0 to pList.Count-1 do
        if Length(pList[I].data)>0 then
        begin
            buffer:=pList[I].data;
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;
    pList.Free;
end;
procedure TUDPClient.SendAck(Ack: Int64);
var
  p:TPacket;
  p2:TPacket;

  o,t:TDateTime;

  buffer:TBytes;
begin
    p.Serial:=SNum;
    p.Next:=Rand();
    SNum:=p.Next;
    p.Index:=Ack;

    p2.Index:=Int64(IA_FAIL);
    p2.Serial:=RNum;
    o:=Date()+Time();
    while not ((p2.Serial=RNum) and (p2.Index=Int64(IA_OK))) do
    begin
        if p2.Serial=RNum then
            SendBuffer(TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p)));

        try
            try
                buffer:=ReceiveBuffer();
                if Length(buffer)>24 then continue;

                p2:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
            except

            end;
        finally
            Finalize(buffer);
            t:=Date()+Time();
            if SecondsBetween(o,t)>=5 then
            begin
                SNum:=p.Serial;
                raise EReadTimeout.Create('Read Timeout');
            end;
        end;
    end;
    SendBuffer(TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p)));

    RNum:=p2.Next;
end;

function TUDPClient.RecvAck(Timeout:Int64): Int64;
var
  p,p2,ap:TPacket;
  buffer:TBytes;

  o,t:TDateTime;
begin
    if Timeout=-1 then
        Timeout:=5000;

    p.Serial:=RNum+1;
    o := Date() + Time();
    while p.Serial<>RNum  do
    begin
      try
        try
          buffer:=ReceiveBuffer();
          if Length(buffer)>24 then continue;

          p := BytesToPacket(buffer);
        except

        end;
      finally
        T := Date() + Time();
        if SecondsBetween(o,T) >= Timeout / 1000 then
          raise EReadTimeout.Create('Read Timeout');
      end;
    end;

    p2.Serial:=SNum;
    p2.Next:=Rand();
    SNum:=p2.Next;
    p2.Index:=Int64(IA_OK);

    o:=Date()+Time();
    t:=o;
    ap.Serial:=RNum+1;
    while True do
    begin
        if SecondsBetween(o,t)>=2 then break;

        SendBuffer(TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p2)));

        try
          try
            buffer:=ReceiveBuffer();
            ap:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
          except
            continue;
          end;
        finally
          t:=Date()+Time();
        end;

        if ap.Serial=RNum then
            break;
    end;

    RNum:=p.Next;
    Result:=p.Index;
end;
procedure TUDPServer.ReadStream(var Stream: TMemoryStream; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
var
  count:Int64;
  ack:TIdAck;

  pList:TList<TPacket>;
  buffer:TBytes;
  packet:TPacket;

  I,J,K:Int64;
  T:Int64;
  Amount:Integer;

  Idxs,Temp:array of Int64;
  nIdx,TempLen,pn:Integer;

  IsFound:Boolean;
  IPIdx:Integer;

  IPNum:TIPNum;
begin
    IPIdx:=FindIPNum(ABinding.PeerIP);
    if IPIdx=-1 then Exit;

    count:=RecvAck(ABinding);

    pList:=TList<TPacket>.Create();
    I:=0;
    T:=0;
    nIdx:=0;
    SetLength(Idxs,MAX_AMOUNT);
    SetLength(Temp,MAX_AMOUNT);
    while I<count do
    begin
        Amount:=RecvAck(ABinding);

        J:=0;
        pn:=nIdx;
        while nIdx<Amount do
        begin
            if T+J>=count then break;

            Idxs[nIdx]:=T+J;
            inc(nIdx);
            inc(J);
        end;

        for J:=1 to Amount do
        begin
            try
                buffer:=ReceiveBuffer(ABinding);
            except
                buffer:=nil;
            end;
            if (buffer=nil) or (Length(buffer)=0) then break;

            packet:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
            if Length(packet.data)=0 then break;

            IsFound:=False;
            K:=0;
            while K<pList.Count do
            begin
                if pList[K].Index=packet.Index then
                begin
                    IsFound:=True;
                    break;
                end;
                inc(K);
            end;

            if IsFound then
                pList.Delete(K);

            pList.Add(packet);
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

        pList.Sort(TComparer<TPacket>.Construct(function(const Left,Right:TPacket):Integer
        begin
            Result:=Left.Index-Right.Index;
        end));

        TempLen:=0;
        for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
        begin
            IsFound:=False;
            for K:=I to pList.Count-1 do
                if pList[K].Index=Idxs[J] then
                begin
                    IsFound:=True;
                    break;
                end;

            if not IsFound then
            begin
                Temp[TempLen]:=Idxs[J];
                inc(TempLen);
            end;
        end;

        J:=I;
        while J < pList.Count do
        begin
            if pList[J].Index <> J then
                break;
            inc(J);
        end;
        I:=J;

        T:=T+Amount-pn;
        Move(Temp[0],Idxs[0],sizeof(Int64)*TempLen);
        nIdx:=TempLen;

        if nIdx=0 then
            SendAck(Int64(IA_OK),ABinding)
        else
        begin
            SendAck(Int64(IA_FAIL),ABinding);
            SendAck(Int64(nIdx),ABinding);
            for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
                SendAck(Int64(Idxs[J]),ABinding);
        end;
    end;
    Finalize(Idxs);
    Finalize(Temp);

    Stream:=PacketsToStream(pList);
    Stream.Position:=0;

    for I:=0 to pList.Count-1 do
        if Length(pList[I].data)>0 then
        begin
            buffer:=pList[I].data;
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

    pList.Free;
end;
procedure TUDPServer.WriteStream(Stream: TMemoryStream; ABinding:TIdSocketHandle);
var
  pList:TList<TPacket>;

  packet:TPacket;
  buffer:TBytes;
  ack,ack2:TIdAck;

  Amount:Integer;
  I,T:Int64;
  ldt,dt,ot:TDateTime;
  J:Integer;

  Idxs:array of Int64;
  nIdx,pn:Integer;

  ncount:Integer;
  Index:Int64;

  IsFound:Boolean;
  IsExcept:Boolean;
  m:Int64;

  IPIdx:Integer;
begin
    IPIdx:=FindIPNum(ABinding.PeerIP);
    if IPIdx=-1 then Exit;

    Stream.Position:=0;
    pList:=StreamToPackets(Stream,ABinding.PeerIP);

    SendAck(Int64(pList.Count),ABinding);

    Amount:=Min(pList.Count,30);
    I:=0;
    T:=0;
    SetLength(Idxs,MAX_AMOUNT);
    nIdx:=0;
    ncount:=0;
    ldt:=-1;
    while I<pList.Count do
    begin
        J:=0;
        while nIdx<Amount do
        begin
            if T+J>=pList.Count then break;

            Idxs[nIdx]:=T+J;
            inc(nIdx);
            inc(J);
        end;

        pn:=nIdx;
        SendAck(Int64(nIdx),ABinding);

        ot:=Date()+Time();
        for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
        begin
            buffer:=PacketToBytes( pList[Idxs[J]] );
            SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,TIdBytes(buffer));
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;

        ack:=TIdAck(RecvAck(ABinding,10000));
        dt:=Date()+Time()-ot;

        T:=T+nIdx-ncount;
        if ack=IA_FAIL then
        begin
            nIdx:=RecvAck(ABinding);
            for J:=0 to nIdx-1 do
                Idxs[J]:=RecvAck(ABinding);

            ncount:=nIdx;
        end
        else
        begin
            ncount:=0;
            nIdx:=0;
        end;

        I:=I+pn-nIdx;

        if ldt<>-1 then
        begin
            if SecondsBetween(ot,ldt)>SecondsBetween(ot,dt) then
                Amount:=Min(Amount+10,MAX_AMOUNT);
            if SecondsBetween(ot,ldt)<SecondsBetween(ot,dt) then
                Amount:=Max(Amount-10,Max(nIdx,30));
        end;

        ldt:=dt;
    end;
    Finalize(Idxs);

    for I:=0 to pList.Count-1 do
        if Length(pList[I].data)>0 then
        begin
            buffer:=pList[I].data;
            Finalize(buffer);
        end;
    pList.Free;
end;
procedure TUDPServer.SendAck(Ack: Int64; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  p:TPacket;
  p2:TPacket;

  IPIdx:Integer;
  o,t:TDateTime;

  buffer:TBytes;
begin
    IPIdx:=FindIPNum(ABinding.PeerIP);
    if IPIdx=-1 then Exit;

    p.Serial:=IPNumList[IPIdx].SNum;
    p.Next:=Rand();
    SetSNum(p.Next,IPIdx);
    p.Index:=Ack;

    p2.Index:=Int64(IA_FAIL);
    p2.Serial:=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum;
    o:=Date()+Time();
    while not ((p2.Serial=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum) and (p2.Index=Int64(IA_OK))) do
    begin
        if p2.Serial=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum then
            SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p)));

        try
            try
                buffer:=ReceiveBuffer(ABinding);
                if Length(buffer)>24 then continue;

                p2:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
            except

            end;
        finally
            Finalize(buffer);
            t:=Date()+Time();
            if SecondsBetween(o,t)>=5 then
            begin
                SetSNum(p.Serial,IPIdx);
                raise EReadTimeout.Create('Read Timeout');
            end;
        end;
    end;
    SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p)));

    SetRNum(p2.Next,IPIdx);
end;
function TUDPServer.RecvAck(ABinding: TIdSocketHandle; Timeout:Int64): Int64;
var
  p,p2,ap:TPacket;
  buffer:TBytes;

  IPIdx:Integer;
  o,t:TDateTime;
begin
    IPIdx:=FindIPNum(ABinding.PeerIP);
    if IPIdx=-1 then Exit;

    if Timeout=-1 then
        Timeout:=5000;

    p.Serial:=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum+1;
    o := Date() + Time();
    while p.Serial<>IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum  do
    begin
      try
        try
          buffer:=ReceiveBuffer(ABinding);
          if Length(buffer)>24 then continue;

          p := BytesToPacket(buffer);
        except

        end;
      finally
        T := Date() + Time();
        if SecondsBetween(o,T) >= Timeout / 1000 then
          raise EReadTimeout.Create('Read Timeout');
      end;
    end;

    p2.Serial:=IPNumList[IPIdx].SNum;
    p2.Next:=Rand();
    SetSNum(p2.Next,IPIdx);
    p2.Index:=Int64(IA_OK);

    o:=Date()+Time();
    t:=o;
    ap.Serial:=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum+1;
    while True do
    begin
        if SecondsBetween(o,t)>=2 then break;

        SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,TIdBytes(PacketToBytes(p2)));

        try
          try
            buffer:=ReceiveBuffer(ABinding);
            ap:=BytesToPacket(buffer);
          except
            continue;
          end;
        finally
          t:=Date()+Time();
        end;

        if ap.Serial=IPNumList[IPIdx].RNum then
            break;
    end;

    SetRNum(p.Next,IPIdx);
    Result:=p.Index;
end;
```

What do you think is the problem?
There is no connection problem. But it sometimes raises EReadTimeout Exception when connected over network while downloading a file.

Environment

OS:Windows 10

Compiler : Delphi 10 tokyo

AP: TP-LINK TL-WR940N PLUS

Tested with My Laptop,PC, Android Phone

My Laptop <-> My Laptop  = worked

My Laptop <-> My PC      = not worked

My Laptop <-> My Phone  (in AP)  = not worked

My Laptop <-> My Phone  (in laptop's hotspot) = worked

Comment: Why are you using UDP for file transfer?  If you actually are in an odd edge case (ie: grid computing) where UDP file transfer is an efficient solution, why aren't you using something like a [UDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-based_Data_Transfer_Protocol) library which has already solved this problem?

Comment: Alternatively, look at [Trivial FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol), which is a UDP-based file transfer protocol, and Indy has client and server components for it

Comment: scouter123 did you sniff the packets to see if it´s comming?? As @RemyLebeau mentioned TFTP is a good alternative. Remy I faced some problemns with TFTP in the past, it seems that the componente wasn´t retry packets when the other side lost. In the same enviroment if I use the TFTP that come with Windows, than it worked. I don´t know if this was fixed...